Organ trafficking action film - possibly with Van Damme or Seagal
I don't remember if the main actor was Van Damme or Steven Seagal.
I remember only there is a gang of organ trafficking and in one of the final scene the "hero" kills the gang killer shooting lying down on a skateboard.
Someone know the title?
Country: USA
YEAR: 1990-94
Genre: action
Is not Pound of Flesh and is not Death Warrant.  

Seems like you should be able to find this by reviewing their IMDb pages... have you done this already?

I was neither able to find a Van Damme nor a Steven Seagal film that met this description.

One of these? - http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=organ-trafficking

nope because is 1990-94 i've refine search and..is not here

I found the movie!
Was Hard Target with Van Damme
But no skateboard!
How Van Damme can shoot without 
something on his back?
The scene is between 01:13:00 and 01:15:00

As a fellow Swede, I must protest. It is obviously Dolph Lundgren in Army of One (1993):

... Well, it would have been, except:

It's not a skateboard, it's a creeper
There's no organ trafficking going on (few organs come out intact after this particular scene)
This is not the final scene

Still, it's an action hero on a "skateboard" in 1993.
